# Does JPQL support the use of a boolean result in another expression?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I am trying to write a query to back a search API. Specifically for a flag `searchDrafts` - if the flag is `true` I have to get rows with `status` `DRAFT` and else I have to get all rows that have any `status` other than `DRAFT`.

In regular SQL, the below query works fine:

```
SELECT id, status
FROM records
where ((status = 'DRAFT') = :searchDrafts);
```

However, a similar thing in JPQL doesn't work:

```
SELECT r 
FROM Records r 
WHERE ((r.status = 'DRAFT') = :searchDrafts);
```

It gives the error:

`unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column nn`

Is there any way in JPQL to use the value of a boolean result in another expression?

The alternative would be doing it the longer way, but its a bit verbose. This works fine in JPQL:

```
SELECT id, status
FROM records
where (:searchDrafts=true AND (status = 'DRAFT')) 
or (:searchDrafts=false AND (status != 'DRAFT'));
```

Comment: You should write this logic in you java program not in the query

Comment: @Jens Its a big query with lot of parameters. JPA supports directly exposing a Repository as a REST endpoint. Are you saying the whole feature in Spring Data JPA is wrong?

Comment: You seem to imply that @RestResource shouldn't be used. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RestResource.html

Comment: @Jens Would be great if you can provide even a code alternative. I am not getting what is the other option in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPQL grammar from Jakarta Persistence 3.0 specification doesn't allow that. (I had 3.0 by hand, but I don't expect that earlier ones differ.) Boolean comparison corresponds to this production rule:

```
comparison_expression ::=
    ...
    boolean_expression {= | <>} {boolean_expression | all_or_any_expression} |
    ...
```

Then `comparison_expression` is only ever encountered as a part of `conditional_expression` production rules:

```
conditional_expression ::= conditional_term | conditional_expression OR conditional_term
conditional_term ::= conditional_factor | conditional_term AND conditional_factor
conditional_factor ::= [NOT] conditional_primary
conditional_primary ::= simple_cond_expression | (conditional_expression)
simple_cond_expression ::=
    comparison_expression |
    ...
```

And `conditional_expression` is what goes directly in `WHEN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` and `ON` clauses. This means that `comparison_expression` cannot be a `boolean_expression`.

Apart from your solution with `AND`, this one seems to work too:

```
SELECT r 
FROM Records r 
WHERE CASE WHEN r.status = 'DRAFT' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END = :searchDrafts;
```

It's quite ugly, but it does convert a `conditional_expression` into a `boolean_expression`.

In practice you'd better have two different queries: one for "=" and the other for "<>".

Overall, it feels like an omission in the JPA standard.